# Vcodec id unknown :XXXX

Tags: raspbian, codec, kodi, mkv, omxplayer

I was trying to watch some X.mkv files on my raspberry pi. I used to have Openelec 3 and this particular X.mkv was running fine. Now I am on Raspbian running Kodi, and I got a black screen when I launched it, so I looked at the logs. They were talking about OMX player. So I decided to try with it.
thus :

```
$ omxplayer -o hdmi /mnt/xx.mkv

Vcodec id unknown : 48323635
have a nice day ...
```

Can anyone tell me which package to install? I did loads of research and can't find which codec to install for this id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use:

```
mediainfo -f "file"
```

I'm quite sure you'll see

> Codecs Video                             : V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC

This is also the x265 format and our little Pis have no way to decode it by hardware. But, OpenElec 3 has a way to do it by software, which is why you were able to watch it there.

Basically use Openelec for most media you want to watch and Raspbian for other things.

Comment: Raspbian Stretch and some later versions of Jessie support OpenGL. So, Pis can now make use of hardware acceleration.